# Outlets cannot connected to repeating content in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, outlet

I'm using Two tableview cells on single tableview like dis...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2ij4.pn)

and when I put subviews on both cells it is showing Outlets cannot connected to repeating content in uitableview

Comment: Image link is not working

Comment: No label,textfields,images everything not working

Comment: you should create a class that inherit from UITableViewCell change class type of UIView in xib file 
those as basics info to handle UI in Xcode

follow a tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

Comment: Thanks Mohamed For Help

Answer (score 0):

You can access the views with the help "tag". First set tag to the required view then access it as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tCell"];
    //I have set CollectionView tag to 100 and Label tag to 50
    UICollectionView *collect = (UICollectionView *) [cell viewWithTag:100]; //if the view is CollectionView
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:50]; //if it is a UILabel
    return cell;
}
```